# Failed to install Automation Anywhere Bot Agent

Tags: rpa, automationanywhere

I am new to Robotic Process Automation (RPA) and I have just started learning Automation Anywhere tool. When I tried to install the Bot Agent I got this error: "Automation Anywhere Bot Agent service install configuration fail to register and return error (5).".

Does anyone know how to fix this issue or how to investigate the root cause of it on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Same error face to me. This works for me well. Try this.**

-> The Bot agent was installed initially and then uninstalled. Uninstalling the Registered Device did not happen correctly and even after removing all the related AA folders from all possible paths from the system, the above error occurred while trying to install the Bot Agent.

**-> Solution :**

i).I figured out that the Automation Anywhere Bot Agent was listed in “Services” app of windows and the corresponding “path to execute” was stamped was wrong. Hence whenever I tried to re-install it, the above error occurred.

ii). Deleted the Automation Anywhere Bot Agent from the “Regedit.exe” (Registry Editor)

iii). Since it was an automatic task in “Services” app of windows, it got removed from Registry Editor but was still listed in Services app with a description of “error (2)”

iv).Opened cmd prompt as Administrator -> navigated to C:\Windows\system32\

v). Executed:  sc delete “Automation Anywhere Bot Agent”

( sc delete "service name which you want to delete" )

vi).Restarted the system and verified on Services app. The Agent was no longer listed.

vii).Re-installed the Agent.

Comment: I did only step (v) and it worked, just delete the service and no restart required. Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: yes, need to do only step (v) but it does require us to restart coz if we redo step (v) again it says that it just registers for deletion. Maybe u have performed some restart-like thing to avoid that